# How can I distribute the two pieces of a game engine in an efficient way?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using VUE and JavaScript to develop an educational 2D game engine for the purpose of teaching kids game design. The breakdown of how I plan on it working is as follows:

1. VUE based editor is used to create game content
2. The actual engine is written in pure JS
3. When the "play," button is clicked in the editor, a function from the engine `run_debug(inputGameData)` is called which returns specific errors to the editor process for it to handle if they appear IE: Display error message and highlight location in editor that the error occurred.
4. When the "export," button is clicked in the editor, the game data and engine are packaged together in a single HTML file to be run as a stand-alone application.

The editor is almost completed, which means I'm now thinking more about the engine side of things. What I'm really scratching my head about is how I should distribute the two on the server without having multiple duplicates of the engine; one version that is generated with the HTML wrapper template, and one that is imported into the VUE application to be run-able from the editor.

I see a few solutions to this off the top of my head, but all have drawbacks:

1. Distribute all separate versions on the server. This will cause a longer page load and hurts my insides as a programmer due to how inefficient this feels
2. Dynamically build the engine from source at export/run time in whichever version is needed. This would cause problems as one of my goals for accessibility is having the editor able to run locally on a machine, and browsers currently don't handle local file reading too well without having to mess about with permissions.
3. Import the HTML5 wrapped version into the VUE app on build, and somehow both call it from the engine (in an Iframe or similar) and be able to read it as text so I can insert the game data on export and download it to the user's machine. I have absolutely no clue how to do this using VUE.

It's a weird niche problem so I'm having some difficulty finding resources on the topic. If anyone has experience in this subject matter I appreciate any help/direction you can give or point me to

Comment: Games usually work as state machines - you can define the state machine as Object and export it to JSON, then your engine can read this JSON and instantiate your state machine. The engine can be packed as any other 3rd party CommonJS library - like jQuery for example. So you call the IIFE which will return the engine instance - and then tell the engine which DOM node it should use for the game, and the actual state machine data.

Comment: That's pretty much how I planned it to work. The issue is that if I import the engine into VUE in a way where I can call it as code, it gets packed into the application. Even if I keep it as a separate file and import it that way, then I don't have a way to open it as a text file and insert the serialized JSON data for packaging the final exported game into a file. I need a way to both run it as code, _and_ read the code as text

Comment: If I was not clear enough in the previous message - you should keep the code (engine) and the game definition (state machine as JSON) separate. The engine can be included in the HTML page with a simple `<script>` tag (so the browser will cache it) - and since it will be IIFE it will create a global variable with its own instance, for example call it `ZachGamesEngine`. You can then access the engine from Vue with `window.ZachGamesEngine`. And the engine does not need to know who is instantiating it - a simple HTML page or your Vue editor.

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem as I still need the VUE editor to be able to package the engine with the JSON into a single HTML file on export, which would require reading the `engine.js` file as text, which HTML doesn't support when doing it this way

Comment: You mean - when I open the Vue application from a local hard drive and it fetches `engines.js` through AJAX the browser will not allow the Vue app to read the AJAX response as text ?

Comment: No, I mean there is no way to go `import engine.js` then later go `let engStr = readfile(engine.js); let template = readfile (template.html); splice(engStr, template, gamedata); save file(template);` (psuedocode obviously). I talked with the developer of Bitsy which is a game engine that does something similar and he said the only way he's found is to just distribute it twice, once packed in the engine and once externally. I don't think there's a solution with current HTML atm

Comment: I did not though you want to `import` the engine - my idea was to use `<html><body><div id="app"></div><script src="engine.js"></script></body></html>` for your Vue app and `<html><body><div id="game"></div><script>var gameDefinition = {<!-- the game state-machine definition here -->};</script><script src="engine.js"></script></body></html>` for the actual game. Anyway, if the author of Bitsy (who certainly should have better experience in the field than me, I am not a game developer) says to pack the engine twice - perhaps there is no better option ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I ended up coming up with (basically option #3 from above, just slightly modified):

1. Create build system for the engine that generates a `engine.js` file where the contents of the file is stored in the format of:

   ```
   let engineCode = 'engineCodeHere';
   let sharedCode = 'code shared between engine and editor goes here';
   ```
2. import the `engine.js` file into the vue editor and on initial load, put the code into `<script>` tags

   ```
   const engineTag = document.createElement('script');
   const sharedTag = document.createElement('script');

   engineTag.id = 'engineCode';
   sharedTag.id = 'sharedCode';
   engineTag.innerHTML = engineCode;
   sharedTag.innerHTML = sharedCode;

   document.body.appendChild(engineTag);
   document.body.appendChild(sharedTag);

   engineCode = null;
   sharedCode = null;
   ```

   once they are imported as script tags the original variables are cleared so we're not story duplicate data in memory.
3. Now, not only do I have access to the runnable js code as if I had imported it normally, but I also have the added benefit of being able to get that code as text so I can use it when packaging the final game "executable."

   ```
   let engineText = document.getElementById('engineCode').innerHTML;
   let sharedText = document.getElementById('sharedCode').innerHTML;
   ```

This will allow me to pack the engine just a single time, instead of once as JS and once as text. For added efficiency I can even hold off creating the engine tag until the game is run in the editor to save on resources.